# filter multiple array of object in which based on contractNumber finding average it's value in javascript but not working in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
vendorArr is Array of Object
```

I was trying to find out by JavaScript ECMA 6 but there was problem while     IE

```
var vendorArr = [
    {
        "contractNumber": 5258,
        "monthId": 0,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "contractNumber": 5258,
        "monthId": 2,
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "contractNumber": 5258,
        "monthId": 3,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "contractNumber": 5656,
        "monthId": 0,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "contractNumber": 5656,
        "monthId": 1,
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "contractNumber": 5656,
        "monthId": 2,
        "value": 4
    }
];
```

Is it possible while JQuery  while => array is not supported in IE and For Each loop is also not supported

Comment: you can use `polyfills` ?

Comment: You can use a library like underscore js, lodash js, or take just that particular function you expect from the library to use it on your own. No need to rebuild the wheel for something that is already built and well tested.

Comment: IE ? Really? Its 2018.
https://pasteboard.co/H7JWnO0.png

Comment: @CristianS. Legacy code amirite, loads of old people still use IE and some older programs run on ActiveX which isn't in Edge for security reasons.